# Jenkins - the creation of the first user with admin rights?

Tags: jenkins

please tell me.

Installed jenkins, clicked global security, add a matrix. Add user with all rights.
Saved, throws on a window prompting you to enter your login and password.

And what is the password? !!! There is no field for entering a password.

How do I make the admin user - this is the main question.
Add a screen to make it clear.

How resets authorization I know. I do not understand how to add the admin user ?

thanks.

[image]

upd to first answer and my comment

[image]

Comment: this "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855944/how-to-create-and-add-users-to-a-group-in-jenkins-for-authentication" should help you

Comment: thanks, I've already understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your root user, keep the other settings and save again (Ignore the exception if any is thrown).

Restart the jenkins service and then call http://your-jenkins-url.com/signup

Here you can add a new user. After the creation you can access the securtity settings page to edit the matrix for your user according to your needs.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Standard+Security+Setup

Comment: thanks a lot. Now I have my user and admin. What to do with the admin account? Or is the group? Attach the screen to the first message.